# Why doesn't the callback function runs in this code?

Tags: callback

I've been trying to run the following code but only the second function runs and the first one does not execute. Can anyone please let me know what's wrong.

```js
function first() {
    setTimeout(function(){
            console.log(1);
          }, 500 );
};
 
function second(first) {
    console.log(2);
};

second();
```

What I'm expecting is that the program first displays 1 after 500ms and then 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you expect :

```
function first() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(1);
        second();
    }, 500 );
};

function second() {
    console.log(2);
};

first();
```

Your 'first' parameter in the second function does nothing. Instead you can do this too :

```
function first(callback) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(1);
        callback();
    }, 500 );
};

function second() {
    console.log(2);
};

first(second);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the effect you're trying to achieve. `first` accepts a callback function as a parameter. It then needs to be called somewhere inside of the `first` function.

```js
function first(callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(1);
    callback(); // Calling the passed function
  }, 500);
};

function second() {
  console.log(2);
};

first(second); // Passing the 'second' function as a callback
```

Comment: you most write `console.log(1)` before `setTimeout`

Answer (score 0):

you just called second. you most call first for callback funtion for you expectation your code shoould be like this

```js
function second() {
   setTimeout(function(){
       console.log(2);
   }, 500 );
};
     
function first() {
   console.log(1);
   second();
};

first();
```

Comment: Yes, but the second() is calling back first() but the output never shows 1. Not even after 2.

Comment: @saadi123 your second function didnt call first. you just have a parameter with name first in your second function